# How do I append the value of a key in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Okay so I have a program I'm writing in python, and it contains a dictionary. The dictiionary as of now looks like:

```
phoneList = {'Tom':'564-0000','Sue':'564-0000','Roberto':'564-0000'}
```

How would I go about adding the same area code to each of the key values. As of now this is what I've com up with, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

```
import copy

def main():

    phoneList = {'Tom':'564-0000','Sue':'564-0000','Roberto':'564-0000'}

    newDict = newDictWithAreaCodes(phoneList)
    #print(newDict)



def newDictWithAreaCodes(phoneBook):

    updatedDict = copy.copy(phoneBook)
    newStr = "518-"
    keyList = phoneBook.keys()   

    for key in keyList:

        del updatedDict[key]
        newKey = newStr + key
        updatedDict[key] = newKey


    print(updatedDict)
```

Comment: And what is the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward with a comprehension:

```
{k:'{}-{}'.format(518,v) for k,v in phoneList.items()}
Out[56]: {'Roberto': '518-564-0000', 'Sue': '518-564-0000', 'Tom': '518-564-0000'}
```

And if I were to write that as a function:

```
def prepend_area_code(d, code = 518):
    '''Takes input dict *d* and prepends the area code to every value'''
    return {k:'{}-{}'.format(code,v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Random comments:

- your `phoneList` is a `dict`, don't call it a `list`.
- also, follow python naming conventions for variables: `phone_list`, methods: `new_dict_with_area_codes`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
area_code = '567'

phoneList = {'Tom':'564-0000','Sue':'564-0000','Roberto':'564-0000'}

phoneList = {k : '-'.join((area_code, v)) for k, v in phoneList.iteritems()}
```

Result:

```
>>> phoneList
{'Sue': '567-564-0000', 'Roberto': '567-564-0000', 'Tom': '567-564-0000'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with dictionary keys and values. Doing `phoneBook.keys()` gives you a list of keys in your `phoneBook` dictionary namely `Tom, Roberto and Sue`. `phoneBook[key]` gives the corresponding values.

I think you mean to concatenate '518' to the values of the keys? Your code concatenates the key to the value. You change this line in your code:

```
newKey = newStr + key
```

to:

```
newKey = newStr + phoneBook[key]
```

This will give you what you want, when you print `updatedDict`:

```
{'Sue': '518-564-0000', 'Roberto': '518-564-0000', 'Tom': '518-564-0000'}
```

---

You can achieve the same using dictionary comprehension like this:

```
>>> phoneList = {'Tom':'564-0000','Sue':'564-0000','Roberto':'564-0000'}
>>> newDict = {k: '518-' + v for k, v in phoneList.items()}
>>> newDict
{'Sue': '518-564-0000', 'Roberto': '518-564-0000', 'Tom': '518-564-0000'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
phoneList = {'Tom':'564-0000','Sue':'564-0000','Roberto':'564-0000'}

for key in phoneList:
    phoneList[key] = '518-' + phoneList[key]
```

produces:

```
{'Roberto': '518-564-0000', 'Sue': '518-564-0000', 'Tom': '518-564-0000'}
```